# Drupal Serial Number

Tags: php, database, drupal, indexing, field

I'm new to drupal, had a good start with basic functionality but I need to do some specific tasks and I'm starting to struggle.

I want a form with a drop down list, that selects a string.
I also want to create a serial number thats unique, and append it to the string.

I was thinking that I'd create a document type "index", then as as document of type index was created increment the number.   I don't know how to create the number in the data base so that its not always reset each time the data base starts.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

I looked at the serial module but this causes my module install to role out with error, I need to disable the module to restore the site.

Comment: Does the serial number need to be incremental, or just unique? If there's a specific algorithm you're using for the serial number, can you provide it?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need:

http://drupal.org/node/249097

Answer (score 0):

I would build something like that with the [computed field module](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field). It allows you to take values from your node form, process them with php and save it to your database as a separate CCK field.